# Download file issue in drupal 7

Tags: 7, files

I am using https://www.drupal.org/project/download_file module to download any file. It is perfectly working on my local machine but on live site when I try to upload any file it gives me the following error[image]

Comment: check permission for `files` directory, it should be writeable by webserver. check this post for further informations on file permission on drupal http://goo.gl/8sYDQ

Comment: Yes I have checked this before, issue with the `Temporary directory` in configuration>filesystem>Temporary directory. Now it is working. Thanku :)